# Item in list change pos when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, android

Any idea how I can make Items stay at the correct position ?
Currently they move position when user scrolls up and down the list. 
I read something about the scripts below, but didn't figure out how to make it work.

```js
 @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
        
@Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
```

My Code:

```js
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < Alarm > {

  private int layout;
  private MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List < Alarm > objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    layout = resource;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;

    final Alarm alarm = alarms.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
      convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
      viewHolder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_days);
      viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_time);
      viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
      viewHolder.switchx = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_switch);

      viewHolder.day.setText(alarm.GetDays());
      viewHolder.time.setText(alarm.GetTime());


      viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          EditAlarm(alarm);
        }
      });

      convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
      //mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      //mainViewHolder.day.setText("hey ");
    }

    return convertView;
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the view "binding" outside of the if/else branches, so that the view is updated every time. Otherwise, you'll get views recycled from nonsense positions.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        mainViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mainViewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);
        mainViewHolder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_days);
        mainViewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_time);
        mainViewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
        mainViewHolder.switchx = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_switch);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Alarm alarm = alarms.get(position);
    mainViewHolder.day.setText(alarm.GetDays());
    mainViewHolder.time.setText(alarm.GetTime());

    mainViewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditAlarm(alarm);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

When `convertView` is null, that means no recycling is happening. Therefore you inflate your layout and create your ViewHolder.

When `convertView` is not null, that means the view is being recycled. This means that you've previously inflated a layout and created a ViewHolder, so all you have to do is retrieve the ViewHolder from the `getTag()` method.

Then, in both cases, you want to populate the view. So regardless of whether or not the view was recycled, you should always update each sub-view (e.g. `day.setText()`).

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are trying is known as ListView ViewHolder pattern, this concept is legacy one as lately RecyclerView is introduced and it's by default having this functionality.

Basically you need to understand why and how Viewholder pattern works, but to give you an idea, when you scroll listview it actually adds new views and that causes performance issues, so when you scroll up and down it should actually re-use the same views/positions which are not visible on the screen! Say for example, let's say your screen accommodates only 4 items, so when you scroll up there it would show you item number 2,3,4,5. So basically only 4 items are visible on the screens and so it should re-use the same item views.

[image]

Image courtesy: https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

Now regarding your code, 2 corrections are needed:

1. you need to set tag in `else` condition.
2. Get an object by position and set data to views outside if/else block

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder;

   if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
       convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  // Notice this change - 1
   }

   Person person = getItem(position);
   holder.nameTextView.setText(person.getName());  // Notice this change - 2

   return convertView;
   ```

   }

Comment: Will look into RecyclerView! Thanks for the info, I just read a bit about ListView so I understood your point. Thanks :)

Comment: @Tore Glad that answer has shown a way! Keep up learning and sharing.